There is no rewarded video placement in the Audience Network for the iOS app
I have an app categorized under 'Entertainment' in the App Store. Currently, I am creating ad placements on Meta's Audience Network, but there is no option for rewarded video in my iOS app.
After reading the documentation, I sent an email to apply for it, but I have not received any response so far. Has anyone encountered the same issue? Please help me with this. Thank you very much!!
ps. my Android app can create rewarded videos, and I am using AppLovin's MAX mediation SDK.
